# enable Flexbox layout grid in Bootstrap 4 beta

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am reading a book about Bootstrap and they state I need to go to:

```
cscc/_variables.scss
```

and change `$enable-flex: false !default;`

to `$enable-flex: true !default;`

Unfortunately, cscc/_variables.scss does not have a variable named: $enable-flex in the beta version of bootstrap.

What should I do enable Flexbox layout grid?

Comment: Flexbox is enabled by default. The $enable-flex var no longer exists.

Comment: oooh, that's nice. Thanks